# how can I recover sound on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, audio, linux-mint

I had 5.1 sound enables and working plus headphones were working. after system updates the sound is gone.
alsamixer shows 2 cards 0: HDMI and 1: Intel PCH.
my 5.1 is plugged in to the three holes in the back.

I just logged in as another user on the same box and the sound is there. so this is some user setting that got messed up. I am not posting the inxi output as this seems to be a user setup problem.
what i see under my account is that Line out is greyed out. it is showing as green in the working account and I can move the slider, but not in my account..
[image: pulse audio mixer]

how do I get my sound back?

Answer (score 0):

quite maddening: there are user settings under advanced where you can deny access to certain devices to the user. audio devices were unchecked. I did not do that and it must have happened as a result of a bug in an update.
anyway after checking the audio devices privilege and restarting the sound is back.